# Выдача функционала главным ботом дочернему telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть задача сделать бота который бы смог создавать других ботов например как в @Nemilin_bot (отправляется токен)

Сделать так что бы человек мог зайти в дочернего бота и при команде /start ему присылалось сообщение с url кнопками и при этом этот бот был создан с помощью другого бота

Кто нибудь знает как можно подобное Реализовать на python+aiogram или же для этого нужно что то другое

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот чтобы конкретно вставить ссылку в кнопку, нужно сделать так

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):    
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
btn = InlineKeyboardButton('Любой текст', url='https://google.com')
keyboard.add(btn)
await message.answer('Текст самого поста если надо', reply_markup=keyboard)
```